# How to hint the browser to display part of a html when the full page is constructing?

Tags: php, html, facebook

In a Facebook canvas app, I'll like to show some static header and banners fast, when the facebook-sdk is connecting to authorize the app/user.

Comment: "hint the browser" what does this mean ?

Comment: for example, is it possible for the php to send some html/images to the browser first, before connecting to facebook ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you think connecting to Facebook API and fetching the information is taking time, then use [output control functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.outcontrol.php).

> The Output Control functions allow you to control when output is sent
>   from the script. This can be useful in several different situations,
>   especially if you need to send headers to the browser after your
>   script has began outputting data. The Output Control functions do not
>   affect headers sent using header() or setcookie(), only functions such
>   as echo() and data between blocks of PHP code.

OR

If you want to show some information before you ask user to authroise the app, you can simply don't ask the user for authorization on load. Based on some user action, you can ask for auhroization.

Answer (score 0):

> when the facebook-sdk is connecting to authorize the app/user.

That means what exactly, what specific actions are you running?

To have no lag from loading the JS SDK from Facebook, you should load it asynchronous – for example see [docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/).

If XFBML tag rendering is slowing page buildup down, then you could initialize it with the option to parse those set to false, and call FB.XFBML.parse later when your content has loaded.

If that doesn’t answer your question satisfyingly – please improve the question.

Comment: "authorize the app/user" means `$facebook = new Facebook(array('appId'=>'...', 'secret'=>'...',));`, `$facebook->getUser();`, `$facebook->api('/me');`

Comment: Ah OK, you’re talking server-side, sorry. Yes, these calls take their time, especially if you do them on every page load (try considering putting the data into a session once you read it, if that’s part of your problem). Flushing parts of the HTML code could work (output control like venu mentioned); but it depends on when you need what kind of FB information to put into your page. Switching to client-side JS for gathering some info/login could also speed things up (XFBML/FB.login etc.)